# Reading in from file but not saving to my array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I can't get my program to read from a file and populate my array.

This is my `StudentAccount` class which contains my array.

The array needs  to be able to populate from a text file
and also add a `Student` by using the `Scanner` class.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {
    // attributes

    private StudentAccount[] list; // to hold the accounts
    private int numStudents; 
    // to keep track of the number of accounts in the list

    // methods
    // the constructor
    public Student() {
        // size array with parameter
        list = new StudentAccount[20];
        numStudents = 0;
    }

    // helper method to find the index of a specified account
    private int search(String studentNameIn) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
            StudentAccount tempAccount = list[i]; 
    // find the account at index i
            String tempName = tempAccount.getStudentName();
    // get account number
            if (tempName.equals(studentNameIn))
    // if this is the account we are looking for
            {
                return i; // return the index
            }
        }
        return -999;
    }

    // return the total number of accounts in the list 
    public int getTotal() {
        return numStudents;
    }

    // check if the list is empty 
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (numStudents == 0) {
            return true; // list is empty
        } else {
            return false; // list is not empty
        }
    }

    // check if the list is full
    public boolean isFull() {
        if (numStudents == list.length) {
            return true; // list is full
        } else {
            return false; // list is empty
        }
    }

    // add an item to the array
    public boolean add(StudentAccount accountIn) {
        if (!isFull()) // check if list is full
        {
            list[numStudents] = accountIn; // add item
            numStudents++; // increment total
            return true; // indicate success
        } else {
            return false; // indicate failure
        }
    }

    // return an account at a particular place in the list
    public StudentAccount getItem(int positionIn) {
        if (positionIn < 1 || positionIn > numStudents) {
            return null; // indicate invalid index
        } else {
            return list[positionIn - 1];
        }
    }

    // return an account with a particular account number
    public StudentAccount getItem(String studentNameIn) {
        int index;
        index = search(studentNameIn);
        if (index == -999) {
            return null; // indicate invalid index
        } else {
            return list[index];
        }
    }

    // remove an account
    public boolean remove(String numberIn) {
        int index = search(numberIn); // find index of account
        if (index == -999) // if no such account
        {
            return false; // remove was unsuccessful
        } else {   // overwrite items by shifting other items along
            for (int i = index; i <= numStudents - 2; i++) {
                list[i] = list[i + 1];
            }

            numStudents--; // decrement total number of accounts
            return true; // remove was successful

        }
    }

    static void writeToFile() {

    }

    static void readFromFile() {

        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Students.txt");

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(strLine);
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }

    }
}
```

This is my `Student` class:

```
public class StudentAccount {

    private String studentName;
    private String studentDOB;
    private String studentAddress;
    private String studentGender;

    public final static String MALE = "m";
    public final static String FEMALE = "f";

    public StudentAccount(String nameIn, String dobIn, 
                      String addressIn, String genderIn) {

        this.studentName = nameIn;
        this.studentDOB = dobIn;
        this.studentAddress = addressIn;
        this.studentGender = genderIn;

    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public String getStudentDOB() {
        return studentDOB;
    }

    public String getStudentAddress() {
        return studentAddress;
    }

    public String getStudentGender() {
        return studentGender;
    }

    public static boolean validateGender(String genderIn) {
        return (genderIn.toLowerCase().compareTo(MALE) == 0)
                || (genderIn.toLowerCase().compareTo(FEMALE) == 0);
    }

}
```

Finally this is my main class which runs my program.

The method for `readFromFile`
I need it to read the file one line at a time and save each line as one student record in the array. It reads in from file but doesn't put any data in the array.

```
public class EnrolmentRegister {

    private static String lecturer = "John Smyth";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char choice;

        Student newStudent = new Student();
        Student.readFromFile();

        do {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1. Add A New Student Account");
            System.out.println("2. Remove A Student Account");
            System.out.println("3. Get Course Details ");
            System.out.println("4. Quit");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please Choose One Of The Options Above");

            choice = InputScanner.nextChar();
            System.out.println();

            switch (choice) {
                case '1':
                    option1(newStudent);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    option2(newStudent);
                    break;
                case '3':
                    option3(newStudent);
                    break;
                case '4':
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry");
            }
        } while (choice != '4');

    }

    static void option1(Student StudentIn) {
        String gender;
        System.out.print("Enter Student Name: ");
        String studentName = InputScanner.nextString();
        System.out.print("Enter Student Date Of Birth: ");
        String studentDOB = InputScanner.nextString();
        System.out.print("Enter Student Address: ");
        String studentAddress = InputScanner.nextString();

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter Student Gender m/f: ");
            gender = InputScanner.nextString();
        } while (!StudentAccount.validateGender(gender));
        // create new account
        StudentAccount account = 
            new StudentAccount(studentName,  studentDOB,
                                 studentAddress, gender);


        // add account to list
        boolean ok = StudentIn.add(account);
        if (!ok) {
            System.out.println("The list is full");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Account created");
        }

    }

    static void option2(Student StudentIn) {
        // get account number of account to remove
        System.out.print("Enter Student Name: ");
        String studentName = InputScanner.nextString();
        // delete item if it exists
        boolean ok = StudentIn.remove(studentName);
        if (!ok) {
            System.out.println("No such Student Name");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Account removed");
        }

    }

    static void option3(Student StudentIn) {
        System.out.println("COM 180, " + lecturer);

    }

    static void option4(Student StudentIn) {

    }

    static void option5(Student StudentIn) {

    }

    }

/*When I call the readFromFile method and print it I get each
  line of text  from the text file but don't know how 
  to put each line from the file into the array. This is
  homework and been at this for days. I know its probably 
  something simple but I cant work it out. Any help would
  be greatly appreciated. Thanks*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see you declare `InputScanner` anywhere as scanner:

```
Scanner InputScanner = new Scanner(new File("fileNameGoesHere"));
```

Yet you call it multiple times in `main`:

```
choice = InputScanner.nextChar(); 
String studentName = InputScanner.nextString();
```

Note: do not capitalize variable names since it may be confused with Object types.

Comment: The scanner is in another class of its own. I just call it when I need it

Comment: Yes but it is not within the scope of `main`. You do not write anywhere that you are pulling it from somewhere else.

Comment: Ah I see. Mistakes on my part. Sorry